# Microsoft DB2 OLE DB Provider :A network library error has occured (6): The handle is invalid

Tags: c#, .net, db2, oledbconnection, oledbexception

I am using `.Net framework 4.5` and `Microsoft OleDb` Provider For **DB2** v6 to connect to db2 and call a stored procedure and read data into data table.

Here is summary of my code which is working fine!

```
    public DataTable SendQuery(OleDbCommand command)
    {
        DataTable table = null;

        lock (lockObj)
        {
            if (connection == null || connection?.State != ConnectionState.Open)
            {
                connection?.Close();

                try
                {
                    connection = new OleDbConnection();
                    connection.ConnectionString = "Provider=DB2OLEDB.1;Password=MyPass;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=MyUser;Initial Catalog=DSNP;Data Source=DSNP;Network Address=5.5.5.5;Network Port=555;Default Schema=MySchema";

                    connection.Open();
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw ex;
                }
            }

            for (int i = 1; i <= _maxRetry; i++)
            {
                try
                {
                    table = null;
                    command.Connection = connection;

                    OleDbDataAdapter adapter = new OleDbDataAdapter(command);
                    table = new DataTable("ResultTable");

                    adapter.Fill(table);
                    break;
                }
                catch (OleDbException ex)
                {
                    connection?.Close();
                    Connect();

                    if (i == _maxRetry) throw ex;
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    throw  ex;
                }
            }
        }
        return (table);
    }
```

This code works fine but some few times with unknown reason I get this error specially when my service calls from another system in network. And here is my stack trace:

> OleDbException: [StackTrace:   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
> at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
> at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)
> at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)
> at ReportDataAccess.DB2Connection.SendQuery(OleDbCommand command),HResult:-2147217900,other:{"oledbErrors":[{"Message":"A network library error has occured (6): The handle is invalid.\r\n","NativeError":6,"Source":"Microsoft DB2 OLE DB Provider","SQLState":"HY000"}],"ClassName":"System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException","Message":"A network library error has occured (6): The handle is invalid.","Data":null,"InnerException":null,"HelpURL":null,"StackTraceString":"   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(OleDbHResult hr)\r\n   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandTextForSingleResult(tagDBPARAMS dbParams, Object& executeResult)\r\n   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommandText(Object& executeResult)\r\n   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteCommand(CommandBehavior behavior, Object& executeResult)\r\n   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReaderInternal(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)\r\n   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand.System.Data.IDbCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.FillInternal(DataSet dataset, DataTable[] datatables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, String srcTable, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable[] dataTables, Int32 startRecord, Int32 maxRecords, IDbCommand command, CommandBehavior behavior)\r\n   at System.Data.Common.DbDataAdapter.Fill(DataTable dataTable)\r\n   at ReportDataAccess.DB2Connection.SendQuery(OleDbCommand command)","RemoteStackTraceString":null,"RemoteStackIndex":0,"ExceptionMethod":"8\nExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling\nSystem.Data, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089\nSystem.Data.OleDb.OleDbCommand\nVoid ExecuteCommandTextErrorHandling(System.Data.OleDb.OleDbHResult)","HResult":-2147217900,"Source":"Microsoft DB2 OLE DB Provider","WatsonBuckets":null}]|

I tried to reconnect or retry filling data table to solve my problem and some times this solution works but sometimes not!
note: this is my first question so if you need more data please comment.

regards

Comment: odbc tracing may help here, to see what is happening under the covers.  If you either have a reproducible scenario, or if you can get control when a retry fails (to allow you do dynamically enable odbc tracing) then tracing may help.   If there are any additional sources of diagnostics (from Microsoft tooling, or from Db2-server diagnostics) around the time of the exceptions then they may also give clues.  Your is a problem determination question, it is not about programming.

Comment: `OleDbCommand`, `DataTable` and `DataAdapter` are `IDisposable`.  You say the code works fine, but how often does it execute a retry?  Because you say remote systems suffer worse, I would hazard a guess that the connection gets broken and code quickly "thrashes with a few failed retries" before exiting. `Dispose()` may be a red herring but is always good practice.  I would move `if (i == _maxRetry) throw ex;` to the top of the `catch (OleDbException ex)` block and introduce a `Thread.Sleep(1000);//play with values in 500-5000` to give things a chance to recover before trying again.